# Activity lifecycle and list of data

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I've spent hours on reading tutorials regarding activity lifecycle but I still don't quite get it. Let's say I have a MainActivity which has a List of some objects which are just model classes. I currently just save them in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore in `onRestoreInstanceState` and it always works, however from what I've read it's not quite the right way to do it.

When app is paused I don't see a point in nulling the list to free memory, because it's still visible, and there are some natural ways in my app where it goes into paused state.

The tricky part is on stop - if it gets killed then `onCreate` gets called, then `onRestoreInstanceState` and all is OK. However if it doesn't, I can't null the list, because the next method is `onRestart` and `onStart` and they don't take `savedInstanceState` as an argument, so I can't restore the data in arrayList, even though I want to free the memory in `onStop`. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's how android Activity works. If you want system to manage your activity life cycle you should not find your own solutions. However, there are some situations when you need to keep some objects alive. You have few options to do that:

Singleton pattern - definetly not the best one. Has many risks , but is easy to implement.

Custom Application class - just extend Application class, add some fields to keep your data, link this class in manifest.

Retain Fragments: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

For me dependency injections with Dagger work well, but this method still have huge overhead, especialy for small projects.

**EDIT:**

Basing on your comment - assuming that you need to display some images in your application - you should create some "static" instance of data cache (for example: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).
You have also provide access to this component and manage it's lifecycle. Natural place for it is custom application class. Here you have some example: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: What I meant was for example a List of images, or something that I want to keep track of - If I null it out in onStop I won't have a way to restore the state if activity goes into restart mode, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to release memory and save states in onStop, this should be done in onDestroy.
When stopped, the Activity keeps the memory alive, but will be destroyed if needed by the system.